# Telegram bot. How to record a user's response after sending a specific message

Tags: c#, .net, telegram-bot

How to record a user's response after sending a specific message.

For example what would it look like in the console:

```
Console.Write("Input some string: ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "to record" ? If (input == "Specific message") {record(input);} ?

Comment: I mean right after a certain message sent by the bot you need to record the user's response

Comment: in the sense that the bot asked a question, the user answered, and their answer will be recorded somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Simple Hack is to create a JSON file with name as the users `user.id`.
Then check the existence for that JSON file during incoming message.
If the file exists then write into it.I don't know Javascript but in python i use `len()` function to check the length of the JSON dict for getting multiple response.